# Getting Mobile Number of a selected Contact

Tags: android, contacts

I want to retrieve of the selected contact.But doesn't returns anything because it generates runtime exception.

```
String[] Phoneprojection = {Phone.NUMBER,Phone.TYPE};
                String[] projection ={Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME};
                String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "=1";
                Cursor cursor = null;
                Cursor phone = null;
                try
                {
                    cursor =  managedQuery(intent.getData(), projection, selection, null, null);
                    while (cursor.moveToNext()) 
                    {           
                       String contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                       // String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

                        phone = managedQuery(Phone.CONTENT_URI,Phoneprojection,Data.CONTACT_ID + "=?",
                                new String[]{String.valueOf(contactId)},
                                null);
                        if(phone.moveToFirst()) {
                            final int contactNumberColumnIndex = phone.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER);
                            final int contactTypeColumnIndex = phone.getColumnIndex(Phone.TYPE);

                            while(!phone.isAfterLast()) {
                                final String number = phone.getString(contactNumberColumnIndex);
                                //final int type = phone.getInt(contactTypeColumnIndex);
                                //final int typeLabelResource = Phone.getTypeLabelResource(type);
                            //  if(typeLabelResource==2)
                                phonenumber.setText(number);
                                Log.e("TAG1",phonenumber.toString());
                                phone.moveToNext();
                            }

                        }                       
                   }  
                }
                catch (Exception npe)
                {
                    Log.e("TAG2", "Error trying to get Contacts."+npe.getMessage());
                }
```

The Log which is generated is:
`Error trying to get Contacts.Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.`

Can anyone explain me how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

your immediatly access the outer cursor, but your not even sure it actually returned with data.

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {           
  String contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
  // String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
```

change the While loop, into a do-while one and call

```
if (!cursor.moveToFirst())
  return;
```

this ensure thats your query actually got a result.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong. There is no Contacts._ID included in your projection.

```
String[] projection ={Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME}; // add Contacts._ID if you wanna query it
String contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
```